# Is this simplification of the volume integral of the curl of a cross product correct?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

To start we have two entities:

the vector field $\vec{P}(\vec{r})$ and the positional vector $\vec{r}$ (in cartesian coordinates for example, $\vec{r} = x\hat{x} + y\hat{y} + z\hat{z}$).

**My question**: Have I simplified the following integral correctly?

$$\int d^3r \space \nabla \times \left(\vec{r} \times \vec{P} \right)$$

**My work**:

$$\nabla \times \left(\vec{r} \times \vec{P} \right) = \vec{r}\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{P}\right) - \vec{P}\left( \nabla \cdot \vec{r} \right)  + (\vec{P} \cdot \nabla)\space \vec{r} \space - (\vec{r} \cdot \nabla) \vec{P}$$

Using $\nabla \cdot \vec{r} = 3$, $(\vec{P} \cdot \nabla)\vec{r} = \vec{P}$, and $(\vec{r} \cdot \nabla) \vec{P} = r \frac{d\vec{P}}{dr} = \frac{d (r\vec{P})}{dr} - \vec{P} \:$ reduces the above equation to:

$$\nabla \times \left(\vec{r} \times \vec{P} \right) = \vec{r}\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{P}\right) - 3\vec{P}  + \vec{P} - r \frac{d\vec{P}}{dr} = \vec{r}\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{P}\right) - 2\vec{P} - \frac{d (r\vec{P})}{dr} + \vec{P}$$

$$\nabla \times \left(\vec{r} \times \vec{P} \right) = \vec{r}\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{P}\right) - \vec{P} - \frac{d (r\vec{P})}{dr}$$

$$ \int d^3r \:\: \nabla \times \left(\vec{r} \times \vec{P} \right) = \int d^3r \:\: \vec{r}\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{P}\right) - \int d^3r \:\:\vec{P} - \int d^3r \:\: \frac{d(r\vec{P})}{dr}$$

Working on the left hand side first:

$$ \int d^3r \:\: \nabla \times \left(\vec{r} \times \vec{P} \right) =  \int d\vec{S} \:\:  \times \left(\vec{r} \times \vec{P} \right) =  \int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{P}) \vec{r} \:\:- \int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{P}$$

Now working on the right hand side:

Decomposing $\int d^3r \:\: \frac{d(r\vec{P})}{dr}$ in spherical coordinates gives:

$$\int d^3r \:\: \frac{d(r\vec{P})}{dr} =  \int\int\int r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi \:\: \frac{d(r\vec{P})}{dr} = \int\int\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi\int r^2 dr \:\: \frac{d(r\vec{P})}{dr}$$

Using integration by parts on the "r" component of the triple integral yields:

$$ \int r^2 dr \:\: \frac{d(r\vec{P})}{dr} = r^2 r\vec{P} - \int dr \:\: 2r^2 \vec{P}$$

replacing the "r" part of the triple integral with the above gives:

$$\int d^3r \:\:r \frac{d\vec{P}}{dr} =  \int\int\int r^2 \sin(\theta)drd\theta d\phi \:\:r \frac{d\vec{P}}{dr} = \int\int\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi \left(r^2 r\vec{P} - \int dr \:\: 2r^2 \vec{P}\right) = \int dS\left(r\vec{P}\right) - 2\int d^3r \vec{P}$$

So putting everything together gives:

$$ \int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{P}) \vec{r} \:\:- \int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{P} = \int d^3r \:\: \vec{r}\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{P}\right) - \int d^3r \:\:\vec{P} - \int dS\left(r\vec{P}\right) + 2\int d^3r \vec{P}$$

$$ \int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{P}) \vec{r} \:\:- \int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{P} = \int d^3r \:\: \vec{r}\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{P}\right) + \int d^3r \:\:\vec{P} - \int dS\left(r\vec{P}\right)$$

Now, at this point I wonder whether it is legitimate to say that:

$$ \int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{P} = \int dS\left(r\vec{P}\right) $$

because the left hand side is a formally a dot product between $d\vec{S}$ and $\vec{r}$ but the right hand side has no dot product.

However, if it is true that $\int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{r}) \vec{P} = \int dS\left(r\vec{P}\right)$, then I arrive at:

$$ \int (d\vec{S} \cdot \vec{P}) \vec{r}  = \int d^3r \:\: \vec{r}\left(\nabla \cdot \vec{P}\right) + \int d^3r \:\:\vec{P} $$

Comment: To say $\int(\mathrm{d}\vec{S}\cdot\vec{r})\vec{P}=\int\,\mathrm{d}S(r\vec P)$ you need to have something like $\mathrm{d}\vec S$ is radial (or some accidental fantastic cancellation is needed), so you want to be integrating over a sphere (or ball for the triple integral) which you didn't state and might not be true.